# FBReader Chinese script?

Tags: android, epub

I downloaded the source of FBReader from [GitHub](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ)

I built the project and ran the project, but I noticed that at some books, some text appears scrambled (as a chinese script or something).

has anybody experienced such a problem before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I added an issue at GitHub and they solved this in the latest update